# Why is the value of the selected row stays the same in textfield?

Tags: java

I've create a jFrame in which I've put a button to get me information from a database to fill JTalble.
I've added a mouse click event to set the value of the selected row in a jTextField.
The problem is the value stays the same.

Here's my code:

```
try {

    int row = jTable4.getSelectedRow();
    String str = (jTable4.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
    String query = "select idclient from client where idclient = '"+str+"' "; 
    rs =(ResultSet) pst.executeQuery();

    if(rs.next()){

        String str4 = rs.getString("idclient");
        jTextField1.setText(str4);
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {

    Logger.getLogger(Display.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `String str4 = rs.getString("idclient");` returns another value as already displayed in `jTextField1`?

Comment: I select the first row it sets 0 to the textfield
I select the 2nd row it also sets 0 to the textfield

Comment: If you print `str4` (with `System.out.println(str4)`) is it 0?

Comment: And what is displayed in `jTextField1` before and after your method? And what should be displayed in our opinion?

Comment: well I think it should display the id of the selected row
0 1 2 and so on
because i want to delete the value from a database

Comment: OK, so the only help I can give are some hints to explore the problem further: (1) check that `int row` is really the correct row of the entry, (2) check that `String str` is really the ID of the client you want. The rest looks good.

Comment: I rewrote the code again and everything worked, didn't figure out what was wrong